# Azure API management with ASE v1

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm struggling with how to use **Azure API management together with App Service Environment v1** (aka ASEv1), i.e. how to set the things via Azure portal.

I have ASE with one app service (target is several of them) and I have APIM gateway pointing to the public host name of the service.

What I have to do to make the app services in ASE VNet to be accessible only through the APIM gateway, to keep the back-end services hidden?

I need to be able to manage APIM from Azure portal and to be able to access the services directly via FTPS for deployment, collecting logs, etc.

--

I've created a new subnet for the APIM and put it in the ASE VNet , where already ASE subnet was. Now I probably have to **set some NSG rules** but I'm not sure how and if it is all I'm supposed to do.

The second thing I'm not sure is how to **change the APIM API settings**. It now points to a public URL of the service - I do not know if it will be available after NSG changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options, depending on what you really want. If you're fine having your backend services visible by outside but not callable, you can employ any means of authentication between APIM and backend services:

- Shared secret - header/query param
- Client certificate authentication
- IP filtering on the side of backend services

If you want to really hide backend services from outside, you'll have to put APIM and ASE into same VNET.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying go the VNet way, added details to the original question.

Comment: I think the easiest way to investigate it is to provision VM inside same VNET, rdp to it and try things out. There is no special magic between APIM and ASE, APIM makes regular HTTP call to a configured endpoint. So as long as you can call your backend from VM, APIM should be able too. I think by default you may not need to touch NSG, subnets in same VNET will be able to communicate at IP level. DNS though may require some setup, I'm not sure if by default public domain names will resolve to VNET IPs, so that is something to check.

Answer (score 0):

Following seems to work, although it may need some fine tuning.

In short, each layer put into separate external VNet with own Network Security Group (NSG), using caller's public IP address to manage access to VNet:

- back-end service web app in ASEv1 VNet "vnet-ase", with associated NSG "nsg-ase"
- APIM gateway put to a separate VNET "vnet-apim", with associated NSG "nsg-apim"
- in nsg-ase allow access from public IP of APIM GW, to vnet-ase
- nsg-apim will be used to manage connections to the APIM gateway